# Copy files everyday from Client to Server using *.bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, client-server

Good day!
I'm new to this so please bear with me.

I need to copy a file from a client computer and send it to a server everyday--at 5pm. Let's say I have 5 clients, the files I need from them have the same file name everyday. Each client have different computer names. The directory of where I get the file is the same.

Example: (CLIENT SIDE) Existing

```
1 Computer Name  STUDENT01 
  Directory      C:\Users\STUDENT01\Documents\Exercises
  File Name      EXER150729.txt
2 Computer Name  STUDENT02 
  Directory      C:\Users\STUDENT02\Documents\Exercises
  File Name      EXER150729.txt
.
.
.
5 Computer Name  STUDENT05 
  Directory      C:\Users\STUDENT05\Documents\Exercises
  File Name      EXER150729.txt
```

Example: (SERVER SIDE) What I need

```
Computer Name  INSTRUCTOR01 
Directory      \\INSTRUCTOR01\Shared\Students Exercises\STUDENT01
Files          EXER150728.txt
               EXER150729.txt
Directory      \\INSTRUCTOR01\Shared\Students Exercises\STUDENT02
Files          EXER150728.txt
               EXER150729.txt
.
.
.
Directory      \\INSTRUCTOR01\Shared\Students Exercises\STUDENT05
Files          EXER150728.txt
               EXER150729.txt
```

Client's and Server's Operating System is Windows XP. They are in the same network. I will create a shared folder \INSTRUCTOR\Shared\Student Exercises with folders \STUDENT01, \STUDENT02 and so on.

Now, the *.bat file will then copy and send the EXERyymmdd.txt to folder STUDENT01 if the Computer Name is STUDENT01.

From what I have seen, *.bat files are only used to [create a backup file to the same computer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wb5DEiYWh7w). Also the [file name of the file to be copied does not change](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-do-i-schedule-an-automatic-file-copy.493716/).

Is it possible to use *.bat files to solve my problem?

I thought of using *.bat files since I don't need a GUI to show the user I'm copying a file. It's automatic.

Comment: So you have a direct access to the target server, via shared folder? So you do not need FTP (you have used [tag:ftp] tag)?

Comment: Folder sharing is ftp right? Since it uses network?

Comment: No it's a completely different protocol.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!

Comment: It's called [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block), but I do not think it's commonly referred to using this name. One usually talks about shared folder, or network path or [UNC path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block). *(comment re-posted with an updated link, originally posted on Jul 30 '15)*

Answer (score 0):

1. I used a batch file from [denzil in a youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wb5DEiYWh7w) named backupcmd.bat. It copies and send all the files inside Exercise folder to Students Exercices.

   @echo off
   :: variables
   set backupdir=\INSTRUCTOR01\Shared\STUDENT01
   set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y

   echo ### Copying Exercises...
   %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Exercises" "%backupdir%"

   echo Copy Complete!
   @pause
2. I used Task Scheduler to run the batch file daily at 5pm.

I'm sorry. The solution was simple. I just made it complicated in my head.